# Why is textillate.js not working on window resize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-textillate

I want to animate my heading whenever the window is resized into pc and mobile view but Textilate only executes on reload.

This is my code:

```
function animateHeading() {
    $('#skysea').textillate({ 
        in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' } 
    });
    $('#on').textillate({ 
        initialDelay: 300,
        in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' } 
    });
    $('#cloud').textillate({ 
        initialDelay: 500,
        in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' } 
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 769) {
        animateHeading();
    }
    if($(window).width() >= 769) {
        animateHeading();
    }
});
```

I want to animate text when the window is resized to pc or mobile view without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/jschr/textillate):

> `$element.textillate('start')` - Manually start/restart textillate

Also, your `resize` functionality is always going to call `animateHeading` as you're checking if the width is less than 769 *and then* checking if it's equal to or greater than 769.

Here's a live example (I've moved the `textillate` selectors/options into a global variable so it can be accessed by both functions):

```js
$(function() {
    // key/val object of selector => textillate options
    var animations = {
        '#skysea': {
            in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' }
        },
        '#on': {
            in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' }
        },
        '#cloud': {
            initialDelay: 500,
            in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' }
        }
    }

    // call textillate using selector/options
    function animateHeading() {
        for (var selector in animations) {
            $(selector).textillate(animations[selector]);
        }
    }

    // call .textillate('start') to start/restart animation as per documentation
    function restartAnimations() {
        // get the selectors as a single string, i.e. "#skysea,#on,#cloud"
        var selectors = Object.keys(animations).join(",");

        $(selectors).textillate('start');
    }

    // animate headings on page load
    animateHeading();

    // bind restartAnimations function on window resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        restartAnimations();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textillate/0.4.0/jquery.textillate.min.js" integrity="sha256-Tvi6rQj7jAzxY1J8UaFlagR6+ZtWVctieK8pFawiY8Q=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.min.js" integrity="sha256-7sov0P4cWkfKMVHQ/NvnWVqcLSPYrPwxdz+MtZ+ahl8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p id="skysea">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p id="on">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p id="cloud">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```